# Config files and Golang or just beginner mistake

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I have done a few tutorials in Go and wanted to try something much more relevant that is going to needed from me relatively soon. Im starting by looking at viper and cobra. I understand the config file is actually for viper to use and cobra is just handling things with it. However, Im stuck on even getting past that point. Ill likely run into a few more errors but I am stuck on this one and any help I find doesnt really make any sense to aid my issue. So I have a decent background in C/C++. And from the reading ampersands and asteriks are used in a similar fashion. Thats why Im having trouble with this.

```
func init() {
     cobra.OnInitialize(initConfig)
     rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVar(&cfgFile, "config", "", "config file (default is $Home/.cobra.yaml)")
     rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&projectBase,"projectbase", "b", "", "base project direcoty eg. github.com")
     rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringP("author", "a", "Rutger", "Written by rutger")
     rootCmd.PersistentFlags().StringVarP(&userLicense, "license", "l", "", "My license homie")
     viper.BindPFlag("author", rootCmd. PersistentFlags().Lookup("author"))
     viper.BindPFlag("projectbase", rootCmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("projectbase"))
     viper.BindPFlag("useViper", rootCmd.PersistentFlags().Lookup("viper"))
     viper.SetDefault("author", "Rutger Luther <rutger.luther@printtrackerpro.com")
     viper.SetDefault("license", "nachos")
}
```

This is basically the example used for viper and cobra from here.  [Go Cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra)

The issue is im getting these errors.

```
cmd\root.go:25:40: undefined: projectBase
cmd\root.go:27:40: undefined: userLicense
cmd\root.go:39:15: undefined: homedir
```

Im making the calls to these for the first time so Im not sure how they would have any values. I apologize if this is a really simply question. But some of these Go pages are a bit more difficult to understand.

Comment: Declare package-level variables for `projectBase` and the others.  Follow the example of `cfgFile`.  Consider filing an issue about the incomplete example code.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. And ill consider it. I just feel since im really fresh theres lot of things that are picked up earlier and Im not privy to all them at this point.  But Ill look into what you stated

Comment: Seriously, everyone started once upon a time. We all wrote bad code when we learn programming languages. Keeping that bad code secret harms you in two ways: *We* can not help you and *you* might miss an opportunity to learn.

Comment: As for the author, a constant flag seems odd to me. [`func(*Command)SetVersionTemplate(string s)`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/cobra#Command.SetVersionTemplate) and its relatives seem to be more suitable.